# One word for things that would be nice to have, but not required to have?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Something a bit professional sounding?

In a scenario where there was also a bunch of ***Requirements***, this situation could be easily solved by labelling one as ***Required*** and this specific bunch of things as ***Optional***. But in an independent context, where no ***requirements*** exist to provide contextual flavor, what can be a concise way of referring to a bunch of things that would be great if you could have / have access to, but they're not things you *need* to have / have access to.

Perhaps the word which fits -  Required : Optional :: Requirements : ????

ETA: Though I'm also hoping for a better word than optional which also conveys the extra / positive nature of 'it would be really good to have this, even if it's not a requirement'.

Comment: nice-to-haves ...

Comment: in hotels they usually put:  With The Compliments

Comment: [Better word for Optional Requirements](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141420/better-word-for-optional-requirements)

Comment: @mplungjan I did find that question, but I'm not really looking in a software feature context, so "optional requirements" definitely sounds oxymoronic without being relevant jargon. Ditto "out of scopes". Nice-to-have works, but well, it doesn't sound so good, hence I was wondering if there was a better word/phrase around.

Comment: Luxuries or Add ons or Pluses

Comment: It would be convenient to have...?

Comment: This really depends on the context. 2 other possibilities: Luxury (economics context), non-essential (this usually conveys a different meaning from "inessential", less strong)

Comment: Requirements : Preferences ?

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or a noun?????

Comment: @Gamemorize: Well, like I said since cognates to both Required and Requirements would be welcome, both adjective and noun options are fine.

Comment: @mplungian: Please consider posting **nice-to-have** as an answer.  It is (to me), clearly the best answer to the question as stated. See also [Must-Have vs Nice-To-Have Requirements](http://jessica80304.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/must-have-vs-nice-to-have-requirements/).

Comment: The context might help here. In job postings, you often see "required skills" as opposed to "preferred skills": https://www.pongoresume.com/blogPosts/634/what-do-required-preferred-and-desired-skills-mean-.cfm

That becomes "preferences" as a stand-alone noun, which may or may not fit your context.

Answer (score 3):

When people draw up budgets for their living expenses, they sometimes distinguish between 
*necessities* and *nonnecessities*, or between *essential expenditures* and *nonessential expenditures*. After paying for the necessary items, the person working within the budget may view the remaining funds as *disposable income*, and the things that he or she purchases with some or all of that leftover money may be termed (in a reasonably professional way) **discretionary items**.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the term **[complement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/complement)**

> A thing that completes or brings to perfection

While the word has a connotation of *complete*, giving it a bit of *essential* tone, it is often used to convey something that it not necessary, but added on. A wine is not necessary to a meal but may be an excellent *complement*.  Similarly, an accessory to a clothing outfit.

This is not to be confused with *compliment*, even though, as @Josh61 suggests, a hotel may give you a **lagniappe** that is a *complement* to your stay, with their *compliments*.

Comment: Thanks for "lagniappe" - I had no idea that word existed!

Answer (score 2):

Desiderata ... but half your audience won't know the word.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how I stumbled on to this forum, but I am so surprised that I feel compelled to post. The word is luxury.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @graym. Nice to see you here. Answers are nearly always better when they contain a link or two so sources. In this case a dictionary definition would suffice. Check out [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/).

Comment: @andy256 I happened to notice that _none_ of the other 13 responders included any sources or links whatsoever in their responses.  Might it be more encouraging to new posters to suggest they conform to practices that _others are following_, rather than recommending that they do (extra) work that no one else (on this question) is doing? Or at least post the same recommendation to everyone else?

Comment: The term "luxury" hits the mark for casual usage, graym27.  Because of the implication that it carries of _conspicuous consumption_  , it is avoided in professional contexts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspicuous_consumption

Comment: @jaxter 1. Your first statement is incorrect. 2. I was served this answer to review, not the others. 3. Look at the votes: none of these answers has more than two upvotes; an answer of any value on this site often garners at least 10 votes *in the first hours*. 4. Recommendations vary over time; see [answer] for current ones. Happy ELUing

Answer (score 1):

I think there are different degrees that you can go with:

If you are conveying that you really want something but it isn't a must - I would say **needs**.

If you don't need it right now but you expect it soon it is a - **wants**.

If you are just giving a wishlist - **non-essentials** or **wishlist items**.

When developing apps we often have a 3-4 scale deep.  We do use nice-to-haves also which usually go between non-essentials and wants or takes place of wants.

> Someone on my team may send me an email and say I found a nice code
>   class that has a few things we are trying to do.  It covers at least 2
>   in-scope items and if you give me an extra 2 days I can add 3 needs
>   and 2 wishlist-items out.  I might email back and say - 'Can you just
>   do the the 3 needs in one day?'

Answer (score 0):

features, perks, bonuses, bonii?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question...    Could be just "Ideas"  or "Suggestions".

Or depending on the situation, "Suggested" Items, Accompaniments, Activities, Preparations, etc.

Or "[May] we suggest" or Owner/management/locals suggest.

Hints / Prompts / In addition / Temptations

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary, desired, superfluous

Answer (score 0):

A (pejorative) term used in project management is "gold plating".

Comment: The term "gold plating" refers to features added by the development team that were _not requested by the sponsor in the first place_.  An important category, but not what the O.P. is referring to, which describes a subcategory of _requested_ features.

Answer (score 0):

The OP does not specify if an adjective or a noun is wanted...

Possible adjective... Advantageous.

It would be advantageous, but not essential, to have experience.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancement, advantage, bonus, extra, improvement

Answer (score 0):

I use "desirable" for non-esstial "nice to have" qualifications.

Answer (score -1):

'Requisites' and 'elective benefits'.

Comment: 'requisites' sounds like it is required.

Comment: It's the word set I'd use. Some things are requisite (required) and others are elective(optional).

Comment: @Mitch This may be a first-language/country-specific response.  The word _requisite's_ primary use is as an adjective, which is common; it's use as a noun in AmE is rare. Terms like "must-haves" and "needs" are more common (btw - it _does_ mean that the item is required).  "Elective" means "open to choice, or optional". http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elective?s=t However, "elective benefits" is a phrase, and the O.P. requested _one word_.  Finally, Mazura offers "optional" to clarify the intended meaning of the adjective "elective"; ironically, that's the preferred term in AmE.

Answer (score -2):

Borrowing from mathematical formalism:

An item or condition which is nice but not required is "sufficient."

An item or condition which is required (but may not be sufficient) is "necessary."

Example:  Flour is necessary to make bread, but not sufficient, as water and leavening are also necessary.

Example:  $20 is sufficient to buy a $5 item, but not necessary, as a mere $5 would do.

Comment: That's not really how "necessary" and "sufficient" work and doesn't match what the question seems to be after.

Comment: @smithkm on the contrary, that is *exactly* how those words work in mathematics.  Failure to use them in this sense when writing a document (not necessarily a math doc) will lead to ambiguity and confusion.

Comment: @carl-wittoft "Sufficient" doesn't mean "nice to have" it means "enough to be certain".  "nice to have" doesn't mean it's enough by itself. "Sufficient" doesn't mean there's anything beyond what will allow the desired state, and if there is, it doesn't refer specifically to that excess which is what the question seems to be about.

Comment: The answer doesn't address the O.P.'s request.

Comment: Both_necessary_ and _sufficient_ describe items that are required _or_ optional. "Sufficient" means _only_ that the condition will satisfy the equation _by itself_. This makes the other _"necessary"_ items, by definition, actually _unnecessary_ when the "sufficient" condition applies. So, there are two states: _All necessary conditions_ are needed when the _sufficient_ condition _is not_ satisfied, or _none of them_ are when it _is_.  This is a _very abstruse_ and confusing use of the concept of "optional" to explain something else.

Comment: @jaxter I don't think you understand the point.  There cannot be a "not necessary any more" condition in math.   A sufficient condition may well be overkill, e.g.  an angle in a triangle is less than 180 degrees, so if angle A is in a triangle, that's sufficient to show it's less than 180.  It's not necessary that A be in a triangle, but it is necessary that A be an interior angle for some polygon.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Given Events A, B, C, and D: Suppose that Event A _alone_ will cause Event B (this is an example of "sufficient"; it is unrelated to "nice to have").  Suppose that Event B can _also_ be caused by both C and D _together_.  If B has already occurred, then either A occurred, or C and D _both occurred_.  At least _one_ of these two cases is necessary.  If both C and D occurred, then A is _not_ necessary. But If A occurred, then neither C nor D is necessary.  So, in each case at least one of A, C and D was first necessary, and then _not necessary_.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft For the record, I scored twin 800's in the Pure and Applied Math SAT's, and went on to get an Engineering Degree.  Sure, I could be making a mistake somewhere, but if I did, it wasn't what you think you found.  Also, talking about math involves a spoken language, _English_, which is (to put it mildly) an imprecise method of communication.  Math is precise, but if the definitions of terms depend on English, they are difficult to describe precisely and succinctly. There may not be a term in math for "not necessary anymore", but that doesn't mean the condition doesn't exist.